# What is the verb for "concept becomes word"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The formation of concept from something is "conceptualize". But what about the formation of word from concept?

I can only think of bad substitutions like: "materialize from concepts" or even "wordify".

As a bonus, it would be even better if your suggestion originates from Cognitive Psychology, Psychology, or Philosophy.

**Edit:** What about specifically in the sense that "an abstract idea (conceptual meaning) becomes a concrete representation (lexical form)"?

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, to turn your ideas into expressions, you *verbalize* them. Except when you are "lost for words".
[**verbalize**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verbalize)  (ODOL)

> (British **verbalise**)
>   verb
>   [with object]
>       **1** Express (ideas or feelings) in words, especially by speaking out loud.
>       ‘*they are unable to verbalize their real feelings*’

Comment: Hi it helps, but what about in the sense that "an abstract idea becomes a concrete representation". Does "verbalize" the transformation from conceptual meaning to "lexical form"?

Comment: @Sean Ideas *are* abstract, in contrast to lexical entities that may be considered *concrete*.

Comment: @Kris Yes. There are different grades of concrete.